# Publish written python program on a website

Tags: python, html, django, server

a total newbie here. I wrote a program in python to compare 2 files and extract the similarity in the output. I want to publish that program in a webpage that will be served in Windows Server 2012, I will probably be using IIS or Apache. The reason why I'm doing it on a server is that I'm working in a company and my boss wants me to allow everyone to use that program without having everyone RDP to the server.

Now I know very basic and limited PHP and HTML, I made the sketch of the webpage there are just 3 buttons/functions, upload 1, upload 2, and run. According to my knowledge which there might be an easier way that I have not yet discover, those buttons have to be configured using PHP to pinpoint every button to work, this is the area where I completely have no idea. I was also wondering if it is possible to install python anywhere on apache that will be on the windows server itself and people can just execute my code any time they need it, but I don't know if it will work or not. The only advice that I got is just people tell me "get Django."

Any advice or tips what should I do next more specific? Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: too broad for SO, first step would surely be to familiarize yourself with Hello world django Program and go on from there.

Comment: First thing you need to figure out is whether you want the program to be executed on the server, or on the user's own computer. If it is the former, then you need to set up django on the web server, and have it act as an API which will receive requests and run your program. Then make a webpage using HTML/CSS/JS (or PHP) and make it send requests to the django API. If it is the latter, then you will have to give them the program in an executable format. This means you can either give them an .exe, or just the python source code. Either way, they have to download some sort of file and run it.

Comment: @stybl thank you sir have a blessed day

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this. You can either invoke Python from PHP like so:

```
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Or you can use a pythonic framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to build and API endpoint on top of your python script

Comment: sorry for my complete lack of knowledge, but that php code you just gave me, what does it do exactly?